# Obtaining rnoaa precipitation data in parallel with foreach

Tags: r, foreach, rnoaa

I am trying to obtain monthly maximum precipitation data using the `rnoaa` package. The data can only be obtained one station at a time, so I'd like to parallelize this step. I tried the following foreach procedure (with just 10 stations) but the resulting data frame has 0 rows and columns. What can I change to obtain the data? Thanks in advance!

Note: An API key can be obtained here: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov//cdo-web/token

```
library(rnoaa)
library(dplyr)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

options(noaakey= "PUT KEY HERE")

stations <- ghcnd_stations()
states <- c("DE","SC","NC","VA","MD","PA")

stations <- stations %>% filter(state %in% states)
unique_stations <- unique(stations$id)

cl <- makeCluster(12, setup_timeout = 0.5)
registerDoParallel(cl)

resultdf <- foreach(i = 1:10,.combine=rbind) %dopar%{
  out <- data.frame()
  for(j in 1950:2023){
    tryCatch(
      expr = {
        pw_prcp_dat <- 
          meteo_pull_monitors(
            monitors = unique_stations[i],
            date_min=paste0(j,"-01-01"),
            date_max = paste0(j,"-12-31"),
            var = "PRCP"
          )
        
        df <- pw_prcp_dat
        df$month <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df$date), "-")))[,2]
        
        aggregate <- df %>%
          group_by(month) %>%
          summarise_at(vars(prcp), list(name = max), na.rm=T)
        
        aggregate$year <- j
        aggregate$id <- unique_stations[i]
        aggregate$latitude <- stations$latitude[stations$id==unique_stations[i]][1]
        aggregate$longitude <- stations$longitude[stations$id==unique_stations[i]][1]
        out <- rbind(out,aggregate)
      },
      error = function(e){
        message('Caught an error!')
        print(e)
      })
  }
  out
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you'd like to share your `noaakey` in plaintext like that? It certainly helps make the question reproducible (nice!) but you may need to regenerate it if that's supposed to stay a secret.

Comment: Good point - I've edited my post and instead included instructions on how to obtain a noaakey. Is that okay?

Comment: Yep, that looks better. The key is still in the post history so you'll have to regenerate the one you've got (if you're worried about others using your API key) but that's all fine. Wish I had helpful advice for the actual problem you've got but I'm not familiar with the package at all.